# Details about Generalized Convolution (Number Theory - Apostol)

Tags: number-theory, convolution

In "Introduction to analytic Number Theory" by Apostol there is chapter about generalized convolution.

Let F denote a real or complex-valued function defined on the positive real axis such that $F(x) = 0$ for $0<x<1$.

$\alpha$ is any arithmetical function.

Generalized convolution is then defined by $(\alpha \circ F)(x)= \sum_{n \leq x} \alpha(n)F(\frac{x}{n})$

Then the text says:

" If F(x) = 0 for all nonintegral values of x, the restriction of F to integers is an arithmetical function and we find that $(\alpha \circ F)(m) =(\alpha \ast F)(m)$"

Here $(\alpha \ast \beta)(n) = \sum_{d | n} \alpha(n)\beta(\frac{n}{d})$.

My question is why does F(x) have to be 0 for all nonintegral values of x for this to work?

Edit: Is the point that we want $F(\frac{x}{n})$ to be 0 when $\frac{x}{n}$ is not an integer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. For example, to isolate $F$, take $\alpha$ to be the unit function $u$. Then the generalized convolution for integer $m \geq 1$ is

$(u \circ F)(m) = \sum_{n \leq m} F(\frac{m}{n})$

If $F(\frac{m}{n}) = 0$ whenever $\frac{m}{n}$ is not an integer, the above sum reduces to

$\sum_{n | m} F(\frac{m}{n}) = (u \ast F)(m)$

I think Apostol could have simply said "If $F(x) = 0$ for all nonintegral values of x, we find that $(\alpha \circ F)(m) = (\alpha \ast F)(m)$ for all integers $m \geq 1$..."